# Dotchart with secondary axis

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to produce a dotchart with a secondary axis on top. However once I plot the second dotchart (with a par(new=T)), I can't figure out how not to display the axis ticks over the previous ones in axis side=1. Here's my code with mock data:

```
y1_i <- c(2,8,2,14,2)
y2_i <- c(15,17,28,22,30)
y1_f <- c(4,9,11,16,7)
y2_f <- c(13,11,16,11,21)

y=c(y1_i,y2_i,y1_f,y2_f)

x <- c("AAEG","AALO","AGAM","ACHR","AALB")

y1=c(y1_i,y1_f)
y2=c(y2_i,y2_f)

dotchart(y1_i,labels=x,xlab="N50 length",xlim = c(0,max(y1)))
par(new=T)
dotchart(y2_i,labels=x,xlim = c(0,max(y2)))
axis(side=3)
```

[image]

Also, if possible, I would like to add a second data set which would be slightly pushed vertically above the first dataset (to not overlap it), but still corresponding to the same y-axis categories.

Thank you for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, by using dotchart2 from the Hmisc package

```
library(Hmisc)

y1_i <- c(2,8,2,14,2)
y2_i <- c(15,17,28,22,30)
y1_f <- c(4,9,11,16,7)
y2_f <- c(13,11,16,11,21)

y=c(y1_i,y2_i,y1_f,y2_f)

x <- c("AAEG","AALO","AGAM","ACHR","AALB")

y1=c(y1_i,y1_f)
y2=c(y2_i,y2_f)
y1_i <- c(2,8,2,14,2)
y2_i <- c(15,17,28,22,30)
y1_f <- c(4,9,11,16,7)
y2_f <- c(13,11,16,11,21)

y=c(y1_i,y2_i,y1_f,y2_f)

x <- c("AAEG","AALO","AGAM","ACHR","AALB")

y1=c(y1_i,y1_f)
y2=c(y2_i,y2_f)

dotchart2(y1_i,labels=x,xlab="N50 length",xlim = c(0,max(y1)))
par(new=T)
dotchart2(y2_i,labels=x,xlim = c(0,max(y2)),xlab="Scaffold number",lines=F,xaxis=F)
axis(side=3,xlab="Scaffold number")
```